# Why I get no speed up with this in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing

I am running the following snippet in Spark, trying to see a speed-up?

```
val howManyPrimes = sc.paralellize(1 to 1000000).filter(isPrime).count()
```

Where `isPrime` is implemented used trial division.

I run spark-shell:

```
spark-shell --master=local[8]
```

I wait for it to startup, and that snippet runs in ~50 seconds.

Then I quit it and open a spark-shell again but now with 1 core:

```
spark-shell --master=local[1]
```

And I again the snippet runs in ~50 seconds. Why?

isPrime is implemented as follows:

```
def isPrime(x: Int):Boolean = {
    var d = 2
    while(d < x) {
        if (x%d == 0) 
            return false
        else d += 1
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: On my laptop the calculation takes around 1.5 sec for 'local[1]' master and around 1 sec for 'local[8]' master. So parallelization gives some benefits.

I can assume that you need to measure execution time more carefully. Looks like you measure it together with Spark context initialization and the actual improvement is hidden because of that.

Comment: I'm guessing the overheard of coordinating 8 cores is more than the speed up gained. Doing that calculation without Spark takes 150ms or so on my machine, so you're not doing much computation - the overheads (start up and worker coordination) are going to swamp that.

Comment: `parallelize` on local mode defaults to 2 partitions.  Try `parallelize(seq, #ofCores)` to use more of your available resources.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Out of curiosity, how did you implement trial division? My laptop is reasonably fast.

Comment: I tested with both 1 and 8 as #ofCores passed on to parallelize with local[8], and counted all primes to 1,000,000, and in both cases it took 250 s.

Comment: `def isPrime(i:Int) = if (i%2== 0) false else { var n = 3; while (n*n<=i && i%n != 0) n =n +2; n*n > i};
(1 to 1000000).filter(isPrime).length`

Comment: @RodrigoStv Your `isPrime` is very inefficient. On the other hand, you want it to be slow so you can investigate the parallelism :)

Comment: Yes, it is slow on purpose. But I still don't get any noticeable speed up... I am not sure if I should test problems on a much larger scale. Or is it that for this problem, the overhead will always make out-of-core take longer? Because each instance of the problem is just an integer and a few loops.... may be just passing around the values to the workers dwarfs it.